# How to Mock methods from parents' class?

Tags: java, unit-testing

Please see the following class I am going to test, the logic is simple, 
First, `checkEmail(Entity)`, then if exist `create(Entity)` a new user, else `update(Entity)` it. But all these three methods inherit from parent class. However, these three method may inherit or override from parent's parent class, which the `ParentController` have a parent class too. Example: `create(Entity)` from `ParentController`'s parent class. `CheckEmail` From `ParentController` itself.

How Can I test in this situation?

```
public class UserController extends ParentController {
@Override
public void createUser(UserEntity userEntity) throws Exception {

 UserEntity existsUser = checkEmail(userEntity.getEmail());
     if (existsUser == null) {
        create(userEntity);
      } else {
          updateExistsUser(existsUser, userEntity);
      }
}
public class ParentController extends BaseController {
    create (Entity entity){ ...some implementation ...};
    Entity update (Entity entity){ ... some imple... return entity};
}
```

Comment: Can you show your Testcase method? It'll help us easily to understand what do you want to test here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by deriving from the class you want to test and then give your own implementation to the methods you want to mock:

```
public class UserControllerMocked extends UserController {
    @Override
    create (Entity entity){ ... your mock code ....};
    @Override
    Entity update (Entity entity){ ... your mock code ... return entity};
}
```

Unit test example:

```
public class UserControllerTest {
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity("test@email.com");
        UserControllerMocked target = new UserControllerMocked();
        target.createUser(userEntity);

        // assertions
    }
}
```

I don't know if a mocking framework can be of help here.

Comment: It works as you said. deriving from the class, then test the method.

Comment: If you find that the answer is correct, you should "accept the answer", by pressing the gray check mark in the upper left corner of this answer, thank you.